# Where am I going?

Tags: riddle

I'm traveling abroad, or maybe not.

I arrive and unpack my bags. Slick stuff is a must.

Billions of billions of shapes, uniform at first glance but not up close.

Ouch, it hurts! But wait until you get to the end and it will be all better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm traveling abroad, or maybe not.

> to the beach

I arrive and unpack my bags. Slick stuff is a must.

> sunscreen

Billions of billions of shapes, uniform at first glance but not up close.

> sand

Ouch, it hurts! But wait until you get to the end and it will be all better.

> The sand is hot but the water cools my feet.

Comment: Another possibility instead of the water being chilly is the hot sand burning your feet, which can often hurt and when you get to the end (close to the shore) the sand is a lot cooler from the water and will not burn you.

Comment: Well done Jasen. And yes, the water cools your feet after being on the hot sand.

Answer (score 4):

You may be lucky and going:

> Skiing

I'm traveling abroad, or maybe not

> You may live  near artificial slopes or in a snowy place or - in June this could be Chile.

I arrive and unpack my bags. Slick stuff is a must

> You unpack your skis, equipment and clothing.

Billions of billions of shapes, uniform at first glance but not up close

> Snowflakes look similar but are physically fractal and it is unlikely that any two snowflakes are alike due to the estimated 10 quintillion water molecules which make up a typical snowflake!

Ouch, it hurts! But wait until you get to the end and it will be all better

> Can fall, but when get to the bottom of the slope it's ok or may go for after ski schnapps .

Comment: Good answer, however not the correct one.

Comment: Well I _was_ going to ask if such a followup activity was really customary where you are, but I looked at your profile and I suppose I have my answer already.

Comment: @kisk I was referring to the drinks. I do very much like this answer (and upvoted it)!

Comment: @Will You're right, off-piste activity is snow joke in my locale. Good puzzle too - I slipped up - if fact I was too confident I even missed explaining 'Slick stuff is a must' which I thought was snow/ice or a play on snow gear-  I like it when I'm outfoxed - by the wily Jasen- ouch! - touche to you!